# python error : 'Too many indices for array' using cross_val_score from sklearn

Tags: python, cross-validation, index-error

I tried to compute a simple cross_val_score with a Logistic regression, but I don't understand why I get an error : "Too many indices for array"

About the data frame, there are 11 input variables, all of them with dtype float64.
There are 2 output variable, quality (int) and cat_quality (string) (which is a categorization of quality, with only two possible values : good / not_good)

There are 1599 observations.

Here is my code :

```
def split_input_output(X):
    target = X[['cat_quality']]
    X = X.drop(['quality','cat_quality'], axis=1) #quality is a non numerical variable
    return X, target

X, y = split_input_output(df.copy())
lr = LogisticRegression()
cross_val_score(lr, X, y)
```

Here is the error message :

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-f8517fdb5e22> in <module>()
      8 
      9 lr = LogisticRegression()
---> 10 cross_val_score(lr, X, y)
     11 
     12 #lr.fit(X, y)

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.pyc in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
    319                                 n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
    320                                 fit_params=fit_params,
--> 321                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    322     return cv_results['test_score']
    323 

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.pyc in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score)
    193             fit_params, return_train_score=return_train_score,
    194             return_times=True)
--> 195         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    196 
    197     if return_train_score:

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.pyc in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    618 
    619         with self._lock:
--> 620             tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
    621             if len(tasks) == 0:
    622                 # No more tasks available in the iterator: tell caller to stop.

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.pyc in __init__(self, iterator_slice)
    125 
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
--> 127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129 

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.pyc in <genexpr>(***failed resolving arguments***)
    189                         pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    190     scores = parallel(
--> 191         delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    192             clone(estimator), X, y, scorers, train, test, verbose, None,
    193             fit_params, return_train_score=return_train_score,

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.pyc in split(self, X, y, groups)
    330                                                              n_samples))
    331 
--> 332         for train, test in super(_BaseKFold, self).split(X, y, groups):
    333             yield train, test
    334 

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.pyc in split(self, X, y, groups)
     93         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
     94         indices = np.arange(_num_samples(X))
---> 95         for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
     96             train_index = indices[np.logical_not(test_index)]
     97             test_index = indices[test_index]

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.pyc in _iter_test_masks(self, X, y, groups)
    624 
    625     def _iter_test_masks(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
--> 626         test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
    627         for i in range(self.n_splits):
    628             yield test_folds == i

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.pyc in _make_test_folds(self, X, y)
    611         for test_fold_indices, per_cls_splits in enumerate(zip(*per_cls_cvs)):
    612             for cls, (_, test_split) in zip(unique_y, per_cls_splits):
--> 613                 cls_test_folds = test_folds[y == cls]
    614                 # the test split can be too big because we used
    615                 # KFold(...).split(X[:max(c, n_splits)]) when data is not 100%

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Thank you for your answers.

Edit : code bellow (I didn't copy all the data visualization part which is quite long and non relevant because I don't modify the data in it)

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Data reading
df_red = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\path\winequality-red.csv', sep=";")
df_white = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\path\winequality-white.csv', sep=";")

# cat_quality
def categorization(X):
    if X<=6:
        cat = "not_great"
    else:
        cat = "great"
    return cat

df_red["cat_quality"] = np.vectorize(categorization)(df_red["quality"])
df_white["cat_quality"] = np.vectorize(categorization)(df_white["quality"])

# Cross validation <<< error at the end of this part
def input_output(X):
    target = X[['cat_quality']]
    X = X.drop(['quality','cat_quality'], axis=1)
    return X, target


from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
def compute_score(clf, X, y) :
    xval = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv = 5)
    return xval

from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression()

# df_red
X, y = input_output(df_red.copy())

compute_score(lr, X, y)
compute_score(lr, X, y).mean()
```

Comment: would help to have pointer to line that the error is reported for and how df is defined.

Comment: The line pointed is the cross_val_score(lr, X, y).
About the df, there are 1599 observations for 10 variables in X, all of them with float64 dtype, and cat_quality (y) is a string variable with 2 possibles values (good / not_good), and no missing value.
What kind of information could I bring with that?

Comment: ok, not sure if I can be more help here. sounds like something is expecting an array to be indexed with less indices than are being provided.  maybe some issue with what is being passed in x or y,  I am assuming you get a stack trace.  figure out where the error starts and track that back to your input conditions.  might help you identify the cause.  sorry I have nothing more to add here.  good luck.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Edit of the question : adding the full error message, with a description of the dataset

Comment: Please also some sample data which is producing the above output.

Comment: I played with the wine quality dataset : http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/


The variable cat_quality is a categorial variable from the original output variable quality, with a simple rule : if quality>=7, cat_quality="great". Else, cat_quality="not_great".

Comment: Can you please add the code by which you have made `df`. Because I am not able to reproduce the error on the wine dataset you provided. On my system, its running correctly including your `split_input_output`. Also you are saying that there are total 12 columns (including cat_quality) but from the link you provided the dataset has 13 columns)

Comment: You're right, my mistake, there are 13 columns including cat_quality, I was a little bit tired when I wrote my question. I edited my message, correcting this part, and adding my code at the end. Thanks a lot for your time and your help.

Comment: Still not getting any error with this code. I tried both in python 2 and python3 with scikit-learn version 0.19.1

Comment: Indeed, I tried after reading your message on a friend's computer, and there were no error... I don't get it. I coded that from Jupyter notebook 5.0.0 with Anaconda 1.6.10. It's in python 2, and scikit-learn version 0.19.0. Is there an issue with my version of scikit-learn, which is obviously older than yours?